# I want to create 21 tables in excel vba but I get Argument not optional error

Tags: excel, vba

**EDIT: I have refined the code.**
Code process

1. Check Text: **TIME**. If found,
2. Create a table range **B29:E30**
3. Repeat same for next tables with *columnoffset:5* *(21 Tables in all)*

---

The code gives me "Argument not optional" error in line *>ListObjects.Add*

```vb
Sub TableCreate()

Dim i As Integer, R As Integer, Rng As Range, Chk As String, ID As String

'Set Var
i = 10
Sheets(1).Activate
R = 0
Set Rng = Range("B29:E30")
Chk = Range("B29").Value

'For loop begin
For i = -10 To i

If Chk = "TIME" Then
ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Rng.Offset(0, R), , xlYes).Name = "SERIAL_NO" & i

R = R + 5 'Next table distance = 5 columns
Chk = Range.Offset(0, 5)
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: "with no success" doesn't tell us much about what happens when you run your code

Comment: Run-time 1004: Application defined or object defined error. Thanks @TimWilliams

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: `Columns("1:16384")` is not valid syntax for referring to a Range.  What is the purpose of the `Intersect` here though?  It only tests whether `WS.UsedRange` in contained in `WS`, which of course it is...

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the line after startSearch:

Comment: Why search if you know the table is at `B29:E30` ?

Comment: @CDP1802 please refer to this image. There are 20 more similar ranges horizontally https://i.stack.imgur.com/JabbE.jpg

Comment: The second Intersect has no meaning either.  You may as well just use `ws.UsedRange`.  Also, when you qualify your range in adding the table you will want `ws` in front of range.  Otherwise it will come from the active sheet and not the intended source.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the input @DarrellH ! As you can see I'm new to vba in excel and need to learn a lot

Answer (score 0):

### **EUREKA!**

Thanks for your answers. Here's the code that got me back in business. Any suggestion to improve or shorten the code is more than welcome. Time to party XD

```
Function TableCreate()
    
    Sheets(2).Select
    'Var declarations
    Dim Rng As Range, i As Integer, a As Integer
    
    Set Rng = Range("B29:DA29")
    i = 0
    a = 1
    
        For a = 1 To 21   'For loop begin
        
        Sheets(2).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("B29:E30").Offset(0, i), , xlYes).Name = "SERIAL_NO_" & a
    
        i = i + 5
        Next a              'For loop end
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

Functions are normally used to return a value otherwise use a Sub.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TableCreate()
    Dim rng As Range, i As Integer
    Set rng = Sheets(2).Range("B29:E30")
    With Sheets(2).ListObjects
        For i = 1 To 21
           .Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "SERIAL_NO_" & i
           Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 5)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```